# Mocking a bean in a Spring context

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

I want to test a Spring bean **A**, of course this bean is part of a
context and it uses other beans to carry out operations.

There is a particular bean **B** in the context that I want to mock for this test, and note that **B** is not injected to **A** (I could handle this case easily with `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` annotations), **B** is injected to **C** that is injected to **D**, that is injected to **A**.

Can I mock only **B** while testing class **A**?
How can you accomplish this ?

Comment: Why would you? If A doesn't use B directly, there's no reason to mock it. Looks like D is all you need to mock.

Comment: have you tried `@MockBean`?

Comment: @dehasi not using SpringBoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming test class is annotated with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, you could try this:

```
@Mock
private B b;

@InjectMocks
@Spy
private C c = new C();

@InjectMocks
@Spy
private D d = new D();

@InjectMocks
private A a = new A();
```

Rapid explanation: B will be mocked. C and D will be created using new (no mock here, so we tag with `@Spy`). `@InjectMocks` will inject B in C, C in D and D in A. Hope it helps. A more complete example is available in this code of mine (just a sample application code) [here](https://github.com/LoreScianatico/J2EESample/blob/master/library.backend-ejb/src/test/java/com/lorescianatico/library/category/service/impl/CategoryServiceBeanTest.java). Notice how real objects and mocked objects are injected in the same class.

If you are using `SpringRunner`, another way is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {A.class, Bmock.class, C.class, D.class})
```

where `Bmock.class` is a mock that you have already created somewhere in your project. This approach also assumes that you have correctly separated interfaces and implementations: it will work only if you autowire B interface in D, not B concrete class.

Comment: oh yes, that makes sense, only one thing, why do we need spy ?

Comment: Spy tells Mockito to not mock that object, but only use it as it comes.

Comment: yes it also makes sense, but could we accomplish something similar using Spring @Autowired, since I'm using Spring runner for my tests?

Comment: Only if you are using SpringRunner or SpringBootIntegrationTest. In the code I posted I'm assuming that the runner is MockitoJUnitRunner, so it needs to know how to inject objects.

Comment: no, I'm using SpringRUnner so I have a context and I only want to mock one bean of this context, is there a way, ? thanks for your time

Comment: well i'm not using spring boot, i'm using Spring 4.3.x so I guess there is no way to accomplish this  but using your first approach, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is how your dependencies look like -

> B -> C -> D -> A

Since you want to test Bean A, the only thing you would want to mock is `D` and should not bother about what what `D` needs. Mockito will do the job for you.

If for testing `A`, you want to mock all the dependencies like `B` and `C`, you are doing it wrong.